# Проблема с распознаванием "прерывистых" цифр

Tags: java, opencv

Есть задача вырезать цифры из картинок, иногда 0 напечатан примерно как (), то есть контуры не соединяются сверху и снизу. По этой причине вырезаю ноль два раза, как решить эту проблему?

```
private static void recDigit(Mat digitMat) {
    List<MatOfPoint> whiteContoursDigit = new ArrayList<>();
    Imgproc.findContours(digitMat, whiteContoursDigit, new Mat(), Imgproc.RETR_LIST, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
    int counter = 1;
    int imageArea = (int) digitMat.size().area();
    double d_min = Double.MAX_VALUE;
    Rect rect_min = new Rect();
    Point image_center = new Point(new double[]{ 0, 0});
    for (MatOfPoint contourDigit : whiteContoursDigit) {
        RotatedRect boundingRectDigit = Imgproc.minAreaRect(new MatOfPoint2f(contourDigit.toArray()));
        double rectangleAreaDigit = boundingRectDigit.size.area();
        if (rectangleAreaDigit > imageArea / 100) {
            Rect rec = Imgproc.boundingRect(contourDigit);
            // find the best candidates
            if (rec.height > digitMat.height() & rec.width > digitMat.width() / 8)
                continue;
            if (rec.height < digitMat.height() / 2 & rec.width < digitMat.width() / 15)
                continue;
            Point pt1 = new Point((double) rec.x, (double) rec.y);
            double d = Math.sqrt(Math.pow((pt1.x - image_center.x), 2) + Math.pow((pt1.y - image_center.y), 2));
            if (d < d_min) {
                d_min = d;
                rect_min = rec;
            }

            int pad = 5;
            rect_min.x = rect_min.x - pad;
            rect_min.y = rect_min.y - pad;

            rect_min.width = rect_min.width + 2 * pad;
            rect_min.height = rect_min.height + 2 * pad;
            try {
                Mat imageROI = new Mat(digitMat, rect_min);
                String fileNameDigit = "C://laba//res//" + counter + ".jpg";
                Imgcodecs.imwrite(fileNameDigit, imageROI);
                counter = counter + 1;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                //e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Параллельные разделяющие линии на картинке есть не всегда, поэтому разделять изображение по ним не получится.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В данном случае - провести морфологическую операцию "[замыкание](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%8F#%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)", состоящую из erosion и dilation.

[Вот эти операции отдельно в OpenCV](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/erosion_dilatation/erosion_dilatation.html#morphological-operations) с картинками.

Сразу комбинированную можно делать: [morphologyEx](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/d86/group__imgproc__filter.html#ga67493776e3ad1a3df63883829375201f)

При выборе подходящего по размеру и форме ядра (в простейшем случае круг или квадрат) это позволит заполнить небольшие пробелы, не сильно нарушая общую форму.